# 3 States of Data - Encryption

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

Three part question about encryption in the 3 data states:

1. In-Transit
2. In-Use
3. At-Rest

**What types of Encryption does Salesforce offer in these 3 states?**

Feel free to break it up further in to finer layers of architecture, Or answer 1 of the States.

Right now I am mainly interested in "In-Use", but a comprehensive answer is preferred, and would benefit later visitors.

I would imagine Salesforce do not offer anything for "In-Use", but I say this because of the lack of finding any reference to it. Chances are they use secure enclaves, but do they encrypt in memory or while on the CPU. If they did it would most likely be part of Shield.

Documented references would also be great.

Comment: this is a bit presumptuous of a question per Community practices --  have you done any research yet? Please see [ask]

Comment: Salesforce has a lot of examples of both at-rest and in-transit variety. The only thing I don't think is used extensively is in-use/secure-enclave type tech.